# How to get user's download folder in Qt?

Tags: qt

How do I get the standard system / user paths in Qt?

What I really need is to get the location of the user's Downloads folder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `QDir::homePath()` to get a `QString` to the home directory of the current user's profile but I'm not sure that there is a "standard" download directory identified by the OS.

Comment: Quite simply: **no.** Since *everyone* should be using Qt 5 by now, [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) and [Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299399/frank-osterfeld)'s [erudite answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3573367/2809027) are your friends. This answer, however, is not.

Answer (score 38):

In Qt 4, there is [QDesktopServices](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html) providing some user paths:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#StandardLocation-enum

It has e.g. Desktop and Documents but no specific Downloads folder.

In Qt 5, use [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html):

```
const QString downloadsFolder = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation);
```

Comment: It bears noting that `QStandardPaths::writableLocation()` may unsafely return "...an empty string if the location cannot be determined." Likewise, the equally unsafe `QStandardPaths::standardLocations()` function may return the empty list "...if no locations for type are defined." In either case, the return value should *never* be assumed to be sane. Callers should *always* explicitly test for emptiness. Lastly, note that `standardLocations()` returns a list and is thus likely to return a sane value more frequently than `writableLocation()`, which only returns a single string.

Answer (score 1):

With Qt 5.15.0, on a fr-FR Linux (Manjaro) :

```
qDebug() << QStandardPaths::displayName(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation);
```

returns :

> "Téléchargement"

This is not the actual French "DownloadLocation" folder name, which is called **"Téléchargements"**, with a plural **s**, because this folder usually contains more than one downloaded file. Btw, English localization seems to be "~/Downloads", according to Qt 5 online help, with the expected plural s.

Therefore, QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation is unreliable in French. If someone may file and follow the bug at Qt, this might help !